# Tutorial on Consuming a WCF service in ASP.Net web site?

Tags: wcf

I'm attempting to create my first WCF service.

I've created the service and now I'm trying to call it from a asp.net (vb) web site and I've tried adding a web reference to it and using the scvutil.exe to consume the service.

So far neither have worked.  It's not letting me declare the service in my code.  If someone could point me to a good tutorial on how to consume a WCF service in an ASP.Net web site that would be great.

I've found numerous on how to use them with AJAX or silverlight or windows apps but nothing on using it in just a plain old website.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858157/consuming-a-wcf-service-c-vs2008-with-3-5-sp1, and many others. I found them simply by searching "consuming wcf service"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Please see [Beginner's Guide to Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd939784.aspx). It's part of the WCF Developer Center on MSDN, which is full of good resources.

---

The link above is broken. Some other links I've found while searching for it:

- Developing Service-Oriented Applications

  - [Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456779.aspx)

    - [Conceptual Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731190.aspx)
    - [Getting Started Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx)

      - [How to: Create a Windows Communication Foundation Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733133.aspx)
    - [Basic WCF Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731067.aspx)

Comment: This link seems to be active and may be of help:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee720180.aspx

Comment: That's about WCF Data Services, which is different.

Answer (score 2):

Just add service reference, use the service reference as using "reference1.xxxx" and then use the client code.

That's all after the initialization. It works for me. Let me know if you require any help.

Comment: could you clarify your answer some more?