# silverlight service reference.cs

Tags: wcf, silverlight-5.0

Im new to using WCF for silverlight, could someone help me please. This is driving me mad!!

my code in service1.cs is:

```
[OperationContract]
    public List<PublishedSoftwareItem> GetSoftwareByArea(int ID)
    {
        ProductionFileManager manager = new ProductionFileManager();
        using (LinqToSQLPublishedSoftwareDataContext con = new LinqToSQLPublishedSoftwareDataContext())
        {
            var listOfSoftware = new List<PublishedSoftwareItem>();
            var getSoftware = from a in con.PublishedSoftwares
                              join b in con.Areas on a.AreaID equals b.AreaID
                              join c in con.ImageDataStores on a.ImageStoreID equals c.ID
                              select new PublishedSoftwareItem
                              {
                                  Description = a.SoftwareDescription,
                                  PublishLink = a.PublishLink,
                                  Title = a.SoftwareName,
                                  SoftwareImage = manager.GetImageFromDatabase(ID)

                              };
            listOfSoftware = getSoftware.ToList();

            return listOfSoftware;
        }

    }
```

when i update my reference.cs gets messed up and the service doesnt work correctly anymore. Ive unchecked the reuse types checkbox and that didnt help. Please someone help. Ask if you need more info

Comment: What is your actual problem ?

Comment: i now get :          ServiceReference.Service1PublishedSoftwareItem;
        ServiceReference.Image;   I no longer get ServiceReference.Service1Client

Comment: If im doing something wrong, someone know a good tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

you should reface this links:

[WCF Service Reference](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/consuming-data-wcf-service.html) and [Get Use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087428/tutorial-on-consuming-a-wcf-service-in-asp-net-web-site)